# Questions regarding objects/calling functions

Tags: javascript, function, object, invocation

So I solved this problem for a class I am taking via project euler, now I need to do it using objects and I've been scouring google but was hoping for some advice on where I might be going wrong. Was trying to store the variables to call for later use, mianly fiboSeq seems to not ever be usable. Am I just calling the function wrong? Any advice or a point in the right direction to study up would be great.

```
function solution(){
  return {
    fibo: function(limit, prev, curr){
      var fiboSeq = [];
      for (curr = curr; curr < limit; curr = prev + curr){
        prev = curr - prev;
        fiboSeq.push(curr);
      }
      return fiboSeq;
    },

    filterEvens: function(index){
      var evens = [];
      fiboSeq.forEach(function(value, index){
        if (value % 2 === 0){
          evens.push(value);
        }
      });
      return evens;
    },

    sum: function(evens){
      sumEvens = 0;
      evens.forEach(function(value, index){
        sumEvens += sumEvens
      });
      return sumEvens;
    }
  }
}

var seqF = solution().fibo(100, 1, 2);
var evenF =  solution().filterEvens(seqF);
var victoryD = solution().sum(evenF);
console.log(victoryD);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fiboSeq` is in the local socpe of `fibo()`. To access it from other functions you should either pass it as an argument or define it outside the returned object.

```
function solution(){
  var fiboSeq = [];
  return {
    fibo: function(limit, prev, curr){
      for (curr = curr; curr < limit; curr = prev + curr){
        prev = curr - prev;
        fiboSeq.push(curr);
      }
      return fiboSeq;
    },
    // ...
  }
```

Comment: No, I think this should be instance based.

Comment: Thanks I moved it outside and got a step further in my testing, think the next snag was I just need to move the variable declarations of the other arrays outside as well. 3 weeks into this class and it seems to always be something so minor that buggers it all up!

Answer (score 0):

Review the following code:

```
function solution(){
  this.fiboSeq = this.evens = [];
  this.fibo = function(limit, prev, curr){
    for(var c=curr,l=limit,p=prev; c<l; c=p+c){
      p = c-p; this.fiboSeq.push(c);
    }
    return this;
  }
  this.filterEvens = function(){
    var fs = this.fiboSeq;
    for(var i=0,l=fs.length; i<l; i++){
      if(fs[i] % 2 === 0){
        this.evens.push(fs[i]);
      }
    }
    return this.evens;
  }
}
var sol = new solution;
var evenF = sol.fibo(100, 1, 2).filterEvens(); 
var eFl = evenF.length;
```

Comment: Thanks for showing another way of attacking it. While digging through google and here I came across "this" many times but it had not come up in class yet. This example will help me figure out how it works!

Comment: `this` just means the current instance, in this case.